# Passing matplotlib objects to functions

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I've wrote some functions to draw circles in the space, using matplotlib. Basically, I pass a 3D Axes object into the function, compute some data, and call the plot method. Here´s my code:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50) 

def plot_circ(axes, color='black', alpha=0.8, **kwargs):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    axes : mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3D.Axes3D
        Where the sphere is plot.
    **kwargs : 
        Arguments forwarded to "plot" method.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """    
    x = cos(t) # Data to draw the circle
    y = sin(t)
    z = np.zeros(t.size)
    
    axes.plot(x, y, z, color, alpha, **kwargs)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect((1,1,1))
    
plot_circ(ax)

plt.show()
```

I get the following error when executing:

```
in plot_circ
    axes.plot(x_hor, y_hor, z_hor, color, alpha, **kwargs)
in set_3d_properties
    zs = np.broadcast_to(zs, xs.shape)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with remapped shapes [original->remapped]: (50,)  and requested shape (1,)
```

Now, if I remove the function and type everything directly, the code works:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import sin, cos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

t = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50) 

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.set_box_aspect((1,1,1))

x = cos(t)
y = sin(t)
z = np.zeros(t.size)
    
ax.plot(x, y, z, color='black', alpha=0.8)

plt.show()
```

I've read the error log, and it seems to be related with np.broadcast_to, and makes no sense since x and z have the same shape.

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/18394

Found this related bug-report, but still, the code works if I remove the function.

Comment: Implicitly expecting function arguments in a specific order is often a source of confusion. Check `axes.plot(x, y, z, color=color, alpha=alpha, **kwargs)` in contrast to your code `axes.plot(x, y, z, color, alpha, **kwargs)`. Just because you call the fifth parameter `alpha` does not mean that matplotlib interprets it as such.

Comment: Man... It solved the problem!
Please, upload your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Feel free to answer your own question, you are allowed to do this. I would not even know what matplotib uses your `alpha` for when not explicitly declared; obviously, it has to be an array of shape `x`. Up to and including `color`, it interprets your implicit inputs as expected, though.

Comment: As an aside: matplotlib3D has a specific `zdir` keyword for [plotting 2D curves in a 3D space.](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/mplot3d/2dcollections3d.html)